# Choosing few columns in external table

Tags: azure, external-tables, polybase

I have a scenario wherein, I have a file(resides in ADLS) which contains 30 columns , but when i am creating external table.. i wanted to pick only 5 columns.

**My question is : is it possible to selectively choose the columns while creating external table.**

Right now creating external table works.. but when i do select query on top of that ext table.. it throws an exception

***HadoopExecutionException: Too many columns in the line***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a view over your external table with just the columns you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), column selection when creating external tables is not supported:

> The column definitions, including the data types and number of columns, must match the data in the external files. If there is a mismatch, the file rows will be rejected when querying the actual data.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that contains 5 columns instead of 30. This view can be used as a source for external tables.